# Vim stuck in "3 files to edit"

Tags: windows, vim

When opening a file with vim instead of putting the whole path I accidentally just wrote the path to the directory. So instead of:

`vi myDirectory/myFile.txt`

I put

`vi myDirectory`

Now vim has taken this to mean that I want to edit all 3 files in this directory and is stuck in that mode. I can quit vim and return to the console, but when I try to open the file with the full path `vi myDirectory/myFile.txt` I get a blank screen with "2 more files to edit" at the bottom. And then when I return to the console the line "3 files to edit" is printed.

How can I exit this situation so that I can continue to use vim normally and edit my file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attempt to `:edit` a directory (or pass one as a command-line argument), Vim usually shows a directory listing and lets you browse files, courtesy of the [`:help netrw`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw) plugin. **Vim does not automatically select all files from a passed directory.**

Based on your report of having additional files also when the desired file's full path is passed, I rather suspect that you somehow have two additional "hidden" arguments to Vim, which Vim interprets as passed files.

This could be caused by a shell alias (in Bash, check `type vi`). Within Vim, you can list the additional files with `:args`; if they are indeed strange, non-filename strings, that might give you a clue (or at least some text to search for).